# Best approach for file browser DB using Python?

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I've been working on a Python app that is evolving into a specialize file browser that organizes files of a certain naming format and path location while ignoring other files, and am in need some insight as to whether there's built-in functionality in Python that I can tap so I don't reinvent the wheel. My app uses os.walk and there are a lot of conditional situations that are complicating the program logic. os.walk loads a set of directories and filenames at a time while doing its walk and my logic is applied to the file names and directory names in hand. I'm now thinking that a better approach would be build a simple DB of directory and file names that I would then query with SQL. The purpose of this latter approach is to have all the files and their paths loaded, which should simplify my programming logic more-so than the piecemeal approach I've taken with os.walk.

This is my first app in Python. I've done a little work with SQL, but not a ton. My current thinking is I'd use os.walk to build a MySQL DB that I would then query with the Python database API to populate my specialized file browser. E.g., the app would query the DB with to the path to all files beginning with "Invoice#". Would building my own DB be the way to go, or are there directory and file name query features I'm overlooking?

Comment: Without knowing how exactly you are filtering file names it's difficult to tell -- however take a look at the [glob module](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/glob.html); it might work in your case.

Comment: If you don't need a lot of program instances accessing the database, I would recommend using sqlite instead of MySql. It stores a SQL DB in a file on disk and doesn't need a server.

Comment: Another approach not requiring a DB would be to use Qt for the GUI and subclass the filter method QFileSystemModel, which in turn can be used in lists, tables, other widgets. This way you wouldn't have to write you own lazy directory parsing.